# OpenGL text rendering does not show any outputted text to the screen

Tags: opengl, rust

I'm trying to port [this](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Render-text) OpenGL text rendering class to Rust, and this is what I have so far:

```rust
use elara_gfx::{gl_info, Shader, Program, VertexArray, Buffer, BufferType, Color, Uniform, WindowHandler, HandlerResult};
use freetype::Library;
use freetype::face::LoadFlag;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::error::Error;
use elara_gfx::GLWindow;
use elara_gfx::types::c_void;

const VERTEX_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
#version 330 core
in vec4 vertex;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vertex.zw;
}
"#;

const FRAGMENT_SHADER: &'static str = r#"
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main() {
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoord).r);
    FragColor = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
"#;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Character {
    pub texture_id: i32,
    pub size: (i32, i32),
    pub bearing: (i32, i32),
    pub advance: i32
}

impl Character {
    fn new(texture_id: i32, size: (i32, i32), bearing: (i32, i32), advance: i32) -> Character {
        Character { texture_id, size, bearing, advance }
    }
}

struct TextRenderer {
    program: Program,
    vao: VertexArray,
    vbo: Buffer,
    characters: HashMap<char, Character>
}

impl TextRenderer {
    fn new() -> Result<TextRenderer, String> {
        let vertex_shader = Shader::new(&VERTEX_SHADER, gl::VERTEX_SHADER)?;
        let fragment_shader = Shader::new(&FRAGMENT_SHADER, gl::FRAGMENT_SHADER)?;
        let program = Program::new(&[vertex_shader, fragment_shader])?;

        let vao = VertexArray::new()?;
        let vbo = Buffer::new()?;
        vao.bind();
        vbo.bind(BufferType::Array);
        vbo.data_empty::<f32>(BufferType::Array, 24, gl::DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        let vertex_attrib = vao.get_attrib_location(&program, "vertex");
        vao.enable_vertex_attrib(vertex_attrib as u32);
        vao.vertex_attrib_pointer::<f32>(vertex_attrib as u32, 4, gl::FLOAT, false, 4, 0);

        vbo.unbind(BufferType::Array);
        vao.unbind();

        let characters: HashMap<char, Character> = HashMap::new();

        Ok(TextRenderer { program, vao, vbo, characters })
    }

    fn load(&mut self, font: &str, size: u32) {
        if !self.characters.is_empty() {
            self.characters.clear();
        }

        let ft = Library::init().unwrap();
        let face = ft.new_face(font, 0).unwrap();
        face.set_pixel_sizes(0, size).unwrap();
        unsafe {
            gl::PixelStorei(gl::UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        }
        // Enable blending
        unsafe {
            gl::Enable(gl::CULL_FACE);
            gl::Enable(gl::BLEND);
            gl::BlendFunc(gl::SRC_ALPHA, gl::ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        }

        // Load first 128 characters of ASCII set
        for c in 0..128 as u8 {
            face.load_char(c as usize, LoadFlag::RENDER).unwrap();
            unsafe {
                let mut texture = 0;
                gl::GenTextures(1, &mut texture);
                gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, texture);
                gl::TexImage2D(
                    gl::TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    gl::RED as i32,
                    face.glyph().bitmap().width(),
                    face.glyph().bitmap().rows(),
                    0,
                    gl::RED,
                    gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    face.glyph().bitmap().buffer().as_ptr() as *const c_void
                );
                gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
                gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
                gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
                gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);

                let character = Character::new(
                    texture as i32,
                    (face.glyph().bitmap().width(), face.glyph().bitmap().rows()),
                    (face.glyph().bitmap_left(), face.glyph().bitmap_top()),
                    face.glyph().advance().x as i32
                );

                self.characters.insert(c as char, character);
            }
        }
        unsafe {
            gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
    }

    fn render_text(&self, text: &str, mut x: f32, y: f32, scale: f32, color: Color) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.program.use_program();
        let color_uniform = Uniform::new(&self.program, "textColor")?;
        color_uniform.uniform3f(color.0 as f32 / 255.0, color.1 as f32 / 255.0, color.2 as f32 / 255.0);
        unsafe {
            gl::ActiveTexture(gl::TEXTURE0);
        }
        self.vao.bind();
        for c in text.chars() {
            let ch = self.characters.get(&c).unwrap();
            let xpos = x + ch.bearing.0 as f32 * scale;
            let ypos = y - (ch.size.1 as f32 - ch.bearing.1 as f32) * scale;
            let w = ch.size.0 as f32 * scale;
            let h = ch.size.1 as f32 * scale;
            let vertices: [f32; 24] = [
                xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0_f32, 0.0,            
                xpos,     ypos,       0.0,     1.0,
                xpos + w, ypos,       1.0,     1.0,

                xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0,     0.0,
                xpos + w, ypos,       1.0,     1.0,
                xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0,     0.0  
            ];
            unsafe {
                gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, ch.texture_id as u32);
                self.vbo.bind(BufferType::Array);
                self.vbo.subdata(BufferType::Array, 0, &vertices);
                gl::DrawArrays(gl::TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
                x += (ch.advance >> 6) as f32 * scale;
                self.vbo.unbind(BufferType::Array);
            }
        }
        self.vao.unbind();
        unsafe {
            gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Handler {
    renderer: TextRenderer   
}

impl Handler {
    fn new() -> Result<Handler, String> {
        let mut renderer = TextRenderer::new()?;
        renderer.load("resources/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 48);
        Ok(Handler { renderer })
    }
}

impl WindowHandler for Handler {
    fn on_draw(&mut self) -> HandlerResult<()> {
        unsafe {
            gl::ClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
            gl::Clear(gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            self.renderer.render_text("This is some sample text", 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Color(255, 255, 255, 1.0))?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let (app, window) = GLWindow::new_with_title("Hi OpenGL!")?;
    window.get_context()?;
    gl_info();
    
    let render_handler = Handler::new()?;

    // Event handling
    app.run_loop(window, render_handler);
    Ok(())
}
```

My current code does not output any text to the screen. I checked with `glGetError()` and it shows that there are no OpenGL errors. I suspect the issue is with the empty preallocated VBO which I'm not filling in with data correctly. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

(Additionally for reproducing this example this is my cargo.toml):

```ini
[package]
name = "font-rendering"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
elara_gfx = { git = "https://github.com/elaraproject/elara-gfx.git" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much more complicated than I anticipated. It actually was due to **two** issues.

First, the vertices were not in normalized screen coordinates, meaning that any rendered content was outside of the viewport. So I needed to manually convert them with:

```rust
let xpos = (x + ch.bearing.0 as f32 * scale) / width;
let ypos = (y - (ch.size.1 as f32 - ch.bearing.1 as f32) * scale) / height;
let w = (ch.size.0 as f32 * scale) / width;
let h = (ch.size.1 as f32 * scale) / height;
```

Second, and this one was more complicated, there was an issue with the library I used, which defined as:

```rust
pub fn subdata<T>(&self, buffer_type: BufferType, offset: isize, data: &[T]) {
    unsafe {
        gl::BufferSubData(
            buffer_type as types::GLenum,
            offset,
            std::mem::size_of_val(&data) as isize,
            data.as_ptr() as *const types::c_void
        )
    }
}
```

The correct code should've been:

```rust
pub fn subdata<T, const N: usize>(&self, buffer_type: BufferType, offset: isize, data: &[T; N]) 
{
    unsafe {
        gl::BufferSubData(
            buffer_type as types::GLenum,
            offset,
            std::mem::size_of::<[T; N]>() as isize,
            data.as_ptr() as *const types::c_void
        )
    }
}
```

This I only realized through using `c2rust` to transpile the working C version of the source code to Rust.